# updating same value in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have been trying to update value of input in angular directive 
issue: when i update value first time it works but when i update it with same value as the first one . it add values

```
return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

    element.datetimepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        format: attrs.format ? attrs.format : "yyyy/MM/dd"
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        var dateUTC = new Date(ev.date.getTime() + (ev.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
        var masking = $filter('mapDateTimeFormat')(attrs.format ? attrs.format : "yyyy/MM/dd");
        var filterApply = $filter('date')(dateUTC, masking);
        $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, filterApply);
        scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

first time when i select value from calendar its like 
**23-10-15**  but if i update same value again, it becomes something like 
**23-1010-2015** and if i select other date it gives me **23-10-16** value.

i cant figure out what m doing wrong as

```
$parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, filterApply);
```

provide me **23-10-15**, so dont know how wrong value gets update

**Angular** : angular 1.2.2

**Calendar** : Bootstrap calendar

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat the date after selecting from UI. When you select date by using Bootstrap calendar, It's date format is different while normal Date() returns different date. You can just use $watch on date and change date format and again set to same variable.

check below link for some more ref.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3615

//copied from some other place

You would not want to replace the scope.ngModel variable, but the value that's behind that variable. You did it already when you read the value in the first line of the link function:

```
 currValue = parseInt(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel))
```

If it's a plain value, like myProperty, you could use that on the scope:

```
scope[attr.ngModel] = newValue
```

But this will not work, if you have an expression-value, like container.myProperty. In that case (and this is the more generic type, you should be aiming for) you'd have to eval the value being set to the scope, like this:

```
scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel + "=" + newValue)
```

I must admit, that the $eval part is a bit ugly, as it is in JavaScript with the eval pendant, but it does the trick. Just keep in mind that it might not work this way, when you want String values to be set. Then you'd have to escape those values.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: i always reformat the value. var dateUTC = new Date(ev.date.getTime() + (ev.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
        var masking = $filter('mapDateTimeFormat')(attrs.format ? attrs.format : "yyyy/MM/dd");
        var filterApply = $filter('date')(dateUTC, masking); this calls on changedate and i m changing format

Comment: check using scope.$eval.

Comment: Sorry my mistake after wasting some time i come to know that issue is not with Angular directive. Its with Bootstrap Date Time Picker as there is format issue and when value doesn't get changed , scope.apply doesn't make much affect . i have fixed it  . Thanks for your Help